# How to display sitemap/navigation for a site using xslt?

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I have a website that has pages and subpages as in the image attached.[image]

Some of the subpages belong to First pagge(About Patient Direct), they have setted 'do not show in menu'.

All right, I want to make an xslt file that will generate an html content like this:

Menu Item 1 (including Home page - About Patient Direct)

-submenu page 1 1

Menu Item 2 (including Home page - About Patient Direct)

-submenu page 2 1

-submenu page 2 2

**How can I do that?**

This is what I have so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

]>

```
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

<!-- Input the documenttype you want here -->
<xsl:variable name="level" select="1"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:if test="$currentPage/@id = $currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@level=$level]/@id">
         <div class="column">
            <h1>
              <a href="#">
                  Home Page - I don't know what to write here
              </a>
           </h1>
          </div>      
  </xsl:if>

        <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@level=$level]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
         <div class="column">
            <h1>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="name() = 'Link'">
                        <a href="{current()/linkUrl}" target="_blank">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName" />
                        </a>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName" />
                        </a>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </h1>
          </div>
        </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

I have also opened a discussion on http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/xslt/33326-How-to-display-sitemapnavigation-for-a-site-using-xslt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally succeeded to do what I have been looking for. Here is the code for those who might be looking for same functionality

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

]>

```
<xsl:template name="menu">
    <xsl:param name="level"/>

    <xsl:variable name="RootNode" select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById(1050)" />
    <div class="column">
        <h1>
            <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl($RootNode/@id)}" style="width:200px;">
                <xsl:value-of select="$RootNode/@nodeName"/>
            </a>
        </h1>
        <xsl:call-template name="submenu_Homepage">
        </xsl:call-template>

    </div>

    <xsl:if test="count($currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@level=$level]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']) &gt; '0'">
        <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@level=$level]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
            <div class="column">
                <h1>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="name() = 'Link'">
                            <a href="{current()/linkUrl}" target="_blank">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName" />
                            </a>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName" />
                            </a>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>

                </h1>

                <xsl:if test="count(current()/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']) &gt; '0'">
                    <xsl:call-template name="submenu">
                        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level+1"/>

                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="submenu">
    <xsl:param name="level"/>
    <ul class="level_{@level}">
        <xsl:for-each select="current()/*[@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
            <li>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">bottom_border</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
                </a>
                <!--case when we have third menu level-->
                <xsl:if test="count(current()/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']) &gt; '0'">
                    <xsl:call-template name="submenu">
                        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level+1"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="submenu_Homepage">
    <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) = '1']">
            <li>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">bottom_border</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="name() = 'Link'">
                        <a href="{current()/linkUrl}" target="_blank">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName" />
                        </a>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName" />
                        </a>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </li>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: you can also go to http://how-to-code-net.blogspot.ro/2012/07/how-to-create-sitemap-for-website-in.html for more details